# Button within InfoPath (2013) form - onclick to external URL

Tags: 2013, infopath, button, sharepoint-server

Within an InfoPath 2013 form on my SharePoint-Site (2013 on-prem)  I would like to include a button, which directs (onclick) to an external URL.

I am pretty new to InfoPath and did not find yet any material on board for solving this requirement.

I need a solution without using SharePoint-Designer, as this tool is strictly prohibited in my company.

Comment: Did you try Link Button using Image? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSxw5B-FNwM

Comment: Is it possible to have link button inside infopath form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my demand with following workaround:

**1)** I created a button in InfoPath (with no rule on)

**2)** On SharePoint, I checked with the dev-tools of Webbrowser (`F12`) the ID of the rendered button:

[image]

**3)** On this site, where the form is displayed, I added a Script-Editor with the following Code (containing the specific ID of the button):

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){ 
document.getElementById("ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_00d4f4ae_096b_445e_8be6_35b5be425a03_FormControl0_V1_I1_PB7").onclick = function() {
    window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com"); 
    }
});
</script>
```